# Nested comments in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a list of comments to an object in bootstrap 3. The list needs to handle nested comments.

I've tried with `media` in bootstrap but the media containers doesn't have full width (http://www.bootply.com/JJyi88KSnn). I have made a red background to illustrate the problem.

Have someone made a beautiful nested comment list? I don't think the `media` component in bootstrap is good enough.

Comment: Any reason you can't just adjust the width of the media containers?

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz, simply add `width: 100%` to `.media-body` or fix it using an additional class. Some media object implementations set `width: 1%` to the `.media-left` and `width: 100%` to the `.media-body`

Comment: It actually works with `width: 1%`. It seems not to be the best solution but it works :) http://www.bootply.com/LullZgyQLI

Answer (score 3):

Why not use media-list component in boostrap 3

Please read documentation 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/

```
<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8904/

Answer (score 0):

The `Boostrap` documentation for `media-object` was not very clear to me and took me some time to figure out how to place the `html`.  Here's a stripped down version of the `html` which you can copy and paste in your cord as a starting point :

#### HTML Code Snippet for `media-object` :

```
<ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#"><img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;"></a>
        </div>


        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>


            <p>Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.</p>


            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Nested media heading</h4>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.

                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="#"><img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;"></a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">Nested media heading</h4>
                            Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="64x64" class="media-object" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Nested media heading</h4>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Important Note:

- `<div class="media-left"></div>` - You need this `div` element even if you don't have an `image` to put in there.  This is what creates the `indentation`.

Good Luck.